# Can you define a variable in in the print function

Tags: python, variables

First of all hello,  I have a really simple question related to *Python 3.5*.
Can you define a variable during print function?

**Example**

```
print(x= 1 + 1)
```

The error I'm getting is

> TypeError: 'x' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Can someone explain why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

As long as i know its not possible to define a variable in print function.

This works

```
print ('x=', 1+1)
```

and prints "x=2", but still 'x' is not a defined variable.

Answer (score 1):

Because in Python, unlike C and C++, assignments are not expressions.  They are statements.

This IS possible in Python 3.8, using the new "walrus" operator:

```
print(x := 1 + 1)
```

but it is not a good practice.  Just do it in two lines.